# NVDA screen reader is not reading aria-labelledby and aria-describedby in Internet Explorer

Tags: accessibility, wai-aria, screen-readers, nvda

I started working on accessibility. aria-labelledby and aria-describedby work fine in Chrome and Firefox but it is not properly read by NVDA in IE.

```
<div id="div1">div 1</div>
<div id="div2">div 2</div>
<div>div 3</div>
<button aria-labelledby="div1 div2 buttonName1"><span id="buttonName1">Test1</span></button>
<br>
<button aria-describedby="div1 div2 buttonName2"><span id="buttonName2">Test2</span></button>
```

Comment: Which version of IE? Which version of NVDA?

Comment: IE 10, Edge, IE 11 and NVDA 2016.2.1

Comment: Ah, then my answer below definitely applies. As for Edge, that is a completely different browser and does not use the same hooks as IE did. Generally NVDA and JAWS users avoid it, but it works with Narrator.

Answer (score 7):

This is a known bug in Internet Explorer. It is unlikely to be fixed since development efforts are focused on Edge. As such, many NVDA users pair with Firefox.

> IE 11 does not support `aria-labelledby` or `aria-describedby` with single or multiple `id` references *unless* the referenced element is what Microsoft classes as an accessible element. IE non-accessible elements can be made into accessible elements by the addition of `tabindex="-1"` as documented or via the addition of an ARIA `role` (when appropriate).

(Unfortunate) example:

```
<p tabindex="-1" id="label-1">label text</p>
...
<input type="text" aria-labelledby="label-1">
```

Read more here: https://www.paciellogroup.com/blog/2014/06/aria-labelledby-aria-describedby-support-popular-windows-browsers/